# Dynamically importing module in python3 - issue

Tags: python, python-importlib

In a project, I want to dynamically import the right module based on a version-number.
For this I'm using importlib, and works find as long as the package is part of the source.

```py
AdminApi = import_module(f"{self.version}", "AdminApi").AdminApi
```

The folder-structure looks like:

```
Admin-Package / 
    - __init__.py  # Contains dynamic class loader
    - admin64/
        - __init__.py  # contains AdminApi v6.4
        - ...
    - admin65/...
        - __init__.py  # contains AdminApi v6.5
        - ...
```

However, now I find myself needing to decouple the code into its own package to re-use in another project.   So I've packaged this part of the source.  This however seems to cause path-related issues.  This seems to mean that importlib cannot help me.

So far, thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54138717/5731101
I've come to this point:

```py
import importlib
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
script_path = os.path.join(path, version, '__init__.py')

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(f"AdminApi", script_path)
AdminApi = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(AdminApi)
```

Unfortunately the `spec.loader.excec_module` fails with error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'AdminApi'` Even thought the class is clearly available in the file supplied via the path.

I would be grateful if anyone can help me out on this.

Comment: Just a q: what's wrong with `if version == 64: import AdminApi64`, etc?  If you only have a few versions your want to handle I would find that more readable, and it would avoid messing with anything like importlib.  Ofc if this dynamic importing is a feature, it might not be a good solution

Comment: That's a fair remark, perhaps I'm overcomplicating.  It would however be a great feature going forward depending on the amount af variations we end up with.  It seems the AdminApi we talk to seems to have some minor changes on every update - which is every month.

Comment: Fair enough.  If you only ever need to talk to *one* AdminApi I would just call it Admin and replace it every time.  But I take it in your use case you need multiple access.. In any case you've got a solution which works fine :)  (the other option btw might be using `admin = __import__(f"Admin{self.version}")` (equivalent to `import f"Admin{self.version}" as admin` if import allowed that.  I don't know, but I suspect that avoiding importlib and going higher level might fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to try another tool in the toolbox of importlib Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67692/5731101

```py
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

foo = SourceFileLoader("AdminAPI", "/path/to/file.py").load_module()
foo.AdminAPI()
```

This approach had no problems detecting the class and simply imported everything correctly.